# How can I get background to show in the bottom two rows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have three rows in my container. I'd like to apply one background across the bottom two rows. I don't want a background on the 1st row. I want to use one background ac I know I missing something, but can't figure out in the code where to edit it. My background only shows up in the first row of columns.

I don't want to apply a class to each .row that needs the background. The point is to specify the background once and have it apply to the two bottom rows.

Here's my bootply:
http://www.bootply.com/X5WsoQbuM1

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="content-section-d">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h2>How many apples can you eat?</h2>
                <p>
                    The apple tree (Malus domestica) is a deciduous tree in the rose family best known for its sweet, pomaceous fruit, the apple. I.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
        <h2>Join us to pick the apples:</h2>
            <div class="row centered-text" id="backgroundazul">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                <h3>4,000,000+</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                <h3>1,500,000+</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                <h3>150,000+</h3>
            </div>
                </div>
             <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                <h3>68,000+</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                <h3>2,000+</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                <h3>3 years</h3>
            </div>
                </div>

               </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
```

Here's my CSS:

```
#backgroundazul {
background: url(http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/green-hexagons-background.png) no-repeat center center;
padding: 0 0 50px 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you want the background for all row use a class and repeat row

```
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */

.backgroundazul {
    background: url(http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/green-hexagons-background.png) no-repeat center center;
   padding: 0 0 50px 0;
}


    <div class="container">

            <div class="row">
                <h2>Join us to access:</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="row centered-text backgroundazul " >
                <hr class="section-heading-spacer">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                <h3>4,000,000+</h3>
              <p>Apples</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                <h3>1,500,000+</h3>
                <p>Oranges</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                <h3>150,000+</h3>
                <p>Mangos</p>
            </div>
             </div>
            <div class="row centered-text backgroundazul " >
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                <h3>68,000+</h3>
                <p>Bananas</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                <h3>2,000+</h3>
                <p>Honeydew</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                <h3>3 years</h3>
                <p>Blueberries</p>
            </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply an `id` to you `.container` element and then apply the background to the `.row` elements.

```html
<div id="backgroundazul" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
#backgroundazul .row {
    background: url(http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/green-hexagons-background.png) no-repeat center center;
    padding: 0 0 50px 0;
}
```

Updated [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/qrxLMdIaT3). Note that you did not wrap your second row of data in a `.row` and will not have the background applied. I do not know if this was intentional or not.

Comment: This was not intentional. I want the background to apply on the bottom two rows. I don't want the background to apply to the row that says Join us to access:

Comment: I don't think you want to wrap your `h2` in a `.row`. The `.row` class is supposed to be used with grid classes (`.col-x-x`). It has negative margins that adjust for the padding applied to the column classes. If you unwrap the `h2` and wrap those couple of `col-x-x` elements in a `.row` my original solution should work fine. It would look like this [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/5cmQVk9sBd). Otherwise You'll want to get a bit more crafty with your CSS selectors or apply a class to each `.row` that needs the background.

Comment: I can't apply a class to each .row that needs the background. The point is to specify the background once and have it apply to the two bottom rows.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple - you just need to insert in your css code a single line, so the code will look like:

```css
#backgroundazul{
background: url(http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/green-hexagons-background.png) no-repeat center center;
background-size: cover;
padding: 0 0 50px 0;
}
```

And that's it :-)